# How to make my rounded box alternate lines color to flow to the borders

Tags: css

I have a rounded box where I display information and would like to show alternate line with a different background color. The problem is the color does not flow to the borders and inbetween cells and it does not appear very nice. Additionally there is a scrollbar that appears when there are many lines and the scrollbar hides the rounded corner (I can probably live with this if it becomes too complicated).

Here is my basic html:

```
 <div style="width:80%">
    <div id="Activity" style="width:100%; display:inline-block; border-radius:20px; border:1px solid black; padding:10px; background-color:black; height:500px; overflow-y:auto; overflow-x:hidden;">
         <table class="list" id="ActivityList" style="width:100%;">
             <thead style="color:white; font-weight:bold;">
                 <tr>
                     <td style="padding-right:10px;">Date/Time</td>
                     <td>Log</td>
                 </tr>
             </thead>
             <tbody>
                <tr><td style="white-space:nowrap; padding-right:10px;">2017/04/23 10:08:03</td><td>Variable Paul is at home updated to False</td></tr>
                <tr><td style="white-space:nowrap; padding-right:10px;">2017/04/23 10:08:03</td><td>Variable Paul is at home updated to False</td></tr>
                <tr><td style="white-space:nowrap; padding-right:10px;">2017/04/23 10:08:02</td><td>Variable Paul is at home updated to False</td></tr>
             </tbody>
         </table>
     </div>
 </div>
```

And here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8gv1nbmm/) showing the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `cellspacing="0"`to remove the space between the cells

And for the scrollbar, remove the overflows from the child div and set it to the parent div or vice versa you fine bellow link for both solutions:

[Solution 1](https://jsfiddle.net/8gv1nbmm/2/)

[Solution 2](https://jsfiddle.net/8gv1nbmm/3/)

For the lines to touch the right/left border, all you have to do is remove the right/left padding of the divs

[**Solution 3**](https://jsfiddle.net/8gv1nbmm/5/)

Comment: Almost. My main point is to make the darkgray lines to touch the borders of the box (to the left and right).